# Why automatically assigned latitude and longitude are not working in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I ran into a problem, set it up location Manager and CLLocation, get the longitude latitude, pass it the schedule calculation method, the method calculates based on location, time and date. The fact is that the schedule determines incorrectly, if you manually lower the latitude into the method, then the correct schedule will be, what is the problem? access to the user's location is available. I also noticed that when the application starts, I have not yet clicked to use my location, for some reason the schedule is already ready, but incorrect

```
extension PrayerTimes { 
init?(coordinates: CLLocation) {
    
    let calendar = Calendar(identifier: Calendar.Identifier.gregorian)
    let components = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: Date())
    var params = CalculationMethod.karachi.params
    params.madhab = .hanafi
    
    
    self.init(
        coordinates: .init(
            latitude: 37.992843,
            longitude:  32.848393),
        date: components,
        calculationParameters: params)
}
}
```

I have extension CLLocation

```
 extension CLLocation {
var latitude: Double {
    return self.coordinate.latitude
}

var longitude: Double {
    return self.coordinate.longitude
}
}
```

and for my SceneDelegate I write

```
         if let prayerTimes = PrayerTimes(coordinates: .init(latitude: 35.78056, longitude: 78.6389)) {
              
              let prayers = Prayer.make(players: prayerTimes)
              
              PrayerManager.shared.configure(prayers: prayers, timeInterval: 1)
          }
```

location file I get hear : https://adrianhall.github.io/swift/2019/11/05/swiftui-location/

I don’t understand why when I get the coordinates in automatic mode, but the schedule is not correct, if I manually write the coordinates of some city, then everything works. Please Help )

Comment: Can you show the code where you handle the receipt of an updated location? And how that code relates to updating your model and views?

Comment: I use adhan frameworks, Location Manager you can see  by link in my post, and I get the location in the manager, pass it in SceneDelegate file:                                                            @ObservedObject var lm = LocationManager()
        let lat = lm.location?.latitude ?? 0
        let log = lm.location?.longitude ?? 0
        
        if let prayerTimes = PrayerTimes(coordinates: .init(latitude: lat, longitude: log))       Maybe I do something wrong) don't have idea

Comment: Getting location is *asynchronous*; it takes time.  You have to implement a location manager delegate to get that.  The code you linked to isn't really suitable for your task, since you don't want to update the SwiftUI view directly when the location changes, you want to update another aspect of your model (prayer times).  When that changes you want to update your view.

Comment: so what I need to do? please right example